# Google Analytics data limits

Tags: google-analytics

We are using Google Analytics on a webshop. Recently we have added enhanced ecommerce to measure more events so we can optimize the webshop. But now we are experiencing less pageviews and other data is missing.

I don't know what it is, but on a specific page we are nog measuring anymore, I removed some items from the ga:addImpression data, and now the pageview is measured again.

I can find limits for GA, but I can't find anything for the amount of data that can be send to GA. Because is this seems to be related to the amount of data that is send to GA. If I shorten the name of a product, the pageview is also measured again. GA is practically broken now for us because we are missing huge numbers of pageviews.

Where can I find these limits, or how will I ever know when I'm running into these limits?

Comment: "If I shorten the name of a product..." Product Name is 500 bytes, that translates to 500 characters at max. Anything that needs to be url encoded takes multiple bytes, so depending on the product name the actual number of character might be much smaller. This might explain your problem.

Comment: Also I i recall correctly the GA debugger extension for Chrome will warn you if a data field has a value that is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one hand, im not sure how are you building your hits but maybe you should keep in mind the payload limits to send information to GA. (The limit is 8Kb)

In the other hand there is a limit in fact that you should consider ([Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/limits-quotas))

> This applies to analytics.js, Android iOS SDK, and the Measurement Protocol.
>
> - 200,000 hits per user per day
> - 500 hits per session
>
> If you go over either of these limits, additional hits will not be processed for that session / day, respectively. These limits apply to Analytics 360 as well.

My best advise is to regulate the amount of events you send really considering which information has value. No doubt EE data is really important so you should partition productImpression hits in multiple ones of the problem is the size. (As shown in the screenshot)

[image: productImpressions]

And finally, migrate to GTM.

EDIT: Steps to see what the dataLayer has in it (in a given moment)

[image: Steps]

Comment: Tnx, I'm pretty sure I'm hitting against the limit of payload (8Kb) because this happens on pages with a lot of payload data. How do you get the screenshot data? And why GTM above Enhanced Ecommerce?

Comment: @Timo002 Right click > Inspect > Console (Tab) > dataLayer. I ll print your dataLayer variable. The GTM comes first, look a at the first number. In orden im getting gtm.js, gtm.dom and after that and before the gtm.load all the productImpressions. I edited the post to give you a better look.

Comment: Oke, I need GTM for that, now working with Enhanced Ecommerce. When there is time left, we may switch to GTM.

Answer (score 2):

A Google Analytics request can send [max about 8KB of data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#using-post):

POST:

> payload_data – The BODY of the post request. The body must include
>   exactly 1 URI encoded payload and must be no longer than 8192 bytes.

URL Endpoint

> The length of the entire encoded URL must be no longer than 8000
>   Bytes.

If your hit exceeds that limit (happens e.g. with large product lists in EEC tracking) it is not (as far as I can tell) processed.

There are also restrictions to field length for some fields (e.g. custom dimension with max 150 bytes, others are detailed in the [parameter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) ).

In some cases the data type is relevant, e.g. if in your event tracking the event value is set to a string the call might fail.

Comment: This is the limit I was looking for. I also thought of field lengt limit, but this doesn't show any limits: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#impression-data.

Comment: @Timo002, analytics.js works with the measurement protocol, so the limits from there apply. Look into the linked parameter reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the page you are looking for [Quota and limits page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas) can help

> These limits apply to the Web Property / Property / Tracking ID.
>
> 10 million hits per month per property
>
> If you go over this limit, the Google Analytics team might contact you and ask you upgrade to [Analytics 360](https://www.google.com/analytics/analytics/#?modal_active=none) or implement client sampling to reduce the amount of data being sent to Google Analytics.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the amount of hits per month. If i send shorter titles (25 characters instead of 60), it already measures the views. So it looks like the amount of data send is the issue, not the number of hits.

Comment: Well you did ask for data limits.  Sending to much data to one field or another is just goning to get chopped off to my knowledge it will still be recorded.